# Creating Visualforce Dashboard Components

Tags: visualforce, dashboard

I am trying to make a custom report for a dashboard in Salesforce lightning. I read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_basic_dashboard_components.htm) on how to create a Visualforce page and then use that as a component on the dashboard. So I did create a VF Page and when I go back into the Dashboard on which I am trying to add this VF page to, I click on + Component and all I see are reports, I cant seem to find a type that says VF pages. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is what I have on the VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" recordSetvar="cases">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:form id="theForm">
            <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
                <apex:outputLabel value="View:"/>
                <apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="list"/>
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!listviewoptions}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:panelGrid>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:dataList var="c" value="{!cases}" id="list">
                {!c.subject}
                </apex:dataList>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

But I only see options to add Reports only nothing else.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_advanced_dashboard_components.htm):

> Visualforce pages that use the Standard Controller can’t be used in
> dashboards

You'll need to write a custom controller for this page.

Comment: Hi @David Cheng, so I followed you'e documentation, copied over the code for the class and the VF page, it's still now showing up under add component option in Dashboard

Comment: Is this only available in Classic?